# How do I calculate the UMVUE of $P(X\leq c)$ where $X_i\sim \mathrm{N}(\mu,9)$?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, normal-distribution

> How do I calculate the UMVUE of $P(X\leq c)$ where $X_i\sim \mathrm{N}(\mu,9)$?

I know that $\mathbf{1}_{\{X_1\leq c\}}$ is an unbiased estimator of $P(X_1\le c)$. Besides, $S=\bar{X}$ is a complete sufficient statistic for $\mu$, so applying Rao-Blackwell once by calculating $\mathrm{E}[\mathbf{1}_{\{X_1\leq c\}}|S=s]$ should give the UMVUE (by Lehmann-Scheffé). How do I proceed from here?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101258/find-the-umvue-for-phi-mu?rq=1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Rao-Blackwell Theorem to find the UMVUE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2674608/use-rao-blackwell-theorem-to-find-the-umvue)